# Pyomo iterative initializer and constraint

Tags: python, pyomo

Hi I had a question about Pyomo initialize.

I had this initializer in my Pyomo model

```
asset_id={}
asset_id[0]=["A1","A2","A3","A4"]
asset_id[1]=["B1","B2","B3","B4"]
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.asset1_id = pyo.Set(initialize=asset_id[0])
model.asset2_id = pyo.Set(initialize=asset_id[1])
```

I am looking for something like the code below if it is possible since I had an unknown asset that I will need to initialize because it is based on the user input.

```
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.asset={}
for i in range(0,2):
   model.asset[i]= pyo.Set(initialize=asset_id[i])
   model.asset[i]= pyo.Set(initialize=asset_id[i])
```

How can I achieve something like shown above as I have tried that way and Pyomo throw me error?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code to achieve your desired initialization as follows:

```
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.asset = {}
for i in range(2):
    asset_id = input(f"Enter asset ids for asset {i+1}: ").split()  # take user input
model.asset[i] = pyo.Set(initialize=asset_id)
```

This code creates an empty dictionary `model.asset` and then loops over a range of 2 to take user input for the asset ids. The user input is split into a list of asset ids, which are then used to initialize the `pyo.Set` object for each asset. This will allow you to initialize an unknown number of assets based on user input.

Comment: Hi when you print(list(model.asset[0])) it shouldnt have thrown an error  which means there is something wrong with model.asset as a dictionary